# Resize only the first image inside a WordPress post with CSS without affecting any other image

Tags: wordpress, css

How can I resize **only** the **first image** present inside a WordPress post with CSS without affecting any other image inside the post. I have tried this so far with no success:

```
.texty p:nth-child(2) > img {
    width: 600px !important;
}
```

Here is the [Demo](http://chillopedia.com/military/world-war-ii-ghosts-merging-the-past-with-the-present/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to target the second `p` element, not the second child. You should therefore use [**`:nth-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) rather than [**`:nth-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Also, the `img` element isn't a direct child of the `p` element. It is a direct child of the child `a` element. The following selector will work given the provided markup:

```
.texty p:nth-of-type(2) > a > img
```